# Segmentation fault in searching for substring in string

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, substring

Im trying to write a method that checks a string to see if it contains a substring. So for example if the user input was "hello" and they were searching the string for "lo" the output would be "true", but if they were searching for "ol" the output would be "false". This is for a class (I'm not looking for someone to do it for me) so i am supposed to do it by hand and not use many built in functions. Right now my code compiles and then gives me a segmentation fault:11.

```
void subsetCheck(char *string, char *srch){
    char str[100];
    char search[100];
    strcpy(str, string);
    strcpy(search, srch);
    int i = 0, j = 0, flag = 0; 
    while(i < strlen(str)){
        if(strcmp(str[i],search[j]) == 0){
            for(j; j < strlen(search); j++){
                if(strcmp(str[i],str[j]) != 0){
                    j = 0;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
        }   
    i++;
    }
    if(flag == 1){
        printf("TRUE");
    }
    else{
        printf("FALSE");
    }
return;
}
```

I edited my code, which entailed some of the things mentioned in the comments as well as rearranging some for loops and added in comments to try and explain what I think I'm doing at each step.

```
void subsetCheck(char *string, char *srch){
    char str[100];
    char search[100];
    strcpy(str, string);
    strcpy(search, srch);
    int i = 0, j = 0, flag = 0, k = 0;
    while(i < strlen(str)){
        for(j; j <= strlen(search);j++){ //for length of the substring during each i iteration 
                if(str[i] == search[j]){ //if position i matches first letter in substring go into for loop
                    for(k; k <= strlen(search);k++){ //create variable k to allow iteration through strin without messing up placement of i, incase entire substrin isnt there
                        k = i;
                    if(str[k] != search[j]){ //if string position k doesnt equal position j, reassign both variables and break out of the loop
                        j = 0;
                        k = i;
                        flag = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    else{ //if it does than assign flag the value of 1 and iterate both variables
                        flag = 1;
                        j++;
                        k++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    i++;
    }
    if(flag == 1){
        printf("TRUE");
    }
    else{
        printf("FALSE");
    }
return;
}
```

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. You have serious type errors.

Comment: Furthermore, at least one of the mistakes you have made in this code was already pointed out in one of your recent similar questions.

Comment: Why take copies of the parameters? If you can't use built in functions why have you got `strlen` and `strcmp`? Why are you passing single characters to `strcmp`? Why is this a `void` function that prints a result instead of returning one?

Comment: This `while(i < strlen(str))` indicates that you don't know what a c string is. Read about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if(strcmp(str[i],search[j]) == 0){
```

`str[i]` and `search[j]` are already single characters. You should use comparison operators instead of `strcmp()` to compare between characters.

Comment: Previously pointed out to this same asker (and accepted!) here two weeks ago, but they didn't learn: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28422153